# Authorized Web API Access from MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I am facing some issue with Azure AD authentication.

> My application architecture is Asp.net MVC Web & Web API as middle ware
>
> > when i am trying to authenticate using AD Token at web API from MVC, i am not able to get any error and even no response from WEB API in Code
> > But if i try accessing the API using browser where i have already used credentials for Authenticating to MVC app it works fine.

Below is the code to access API but it didn't worked

```
     AuthenticationResult result = null;
        string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        string ApiClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ApiClientId"];
        string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ApplicationURI"];
        string postLoginRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
        string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

      IConfidentialClientApplication app = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();

        var account = await app.GetAccountAsync(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetMsalAccountId());
        string[] scopes = { "openid profile offline_access email User.Read" };
        try
        {
            // try to get an already cached token
            result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
     {
              
          // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync.
            // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
            //Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

            try
            {
                // Build the auth code request Uri
                  string authReqUrl = await OAuth2RequestManager.GenerateAuthorizationRequestUrl(scopes, app, this.HttpContext, Url);

             
            }
            catch (MsalException msalex)
            {
                Response.Write($"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}");
            }
        }
   
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        //apiUrl      client.BaseAddress = apiUrl;
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiUrl + "api/General/GetUserDetailsByEmailAddress?emailAddress=ikhlesh.saxena@amexassetmanagement.com");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your scopes allow you to access your API. Also, you need to debug on the API side whether the token is coming with a request, and if yes how it's validated.